# Where can I get a typhoid vaccination in Zagreb?

Tags: health, us-citizens, croatia

I'm an American tourist in Zagreb. My country's government health organization recommends I get a typhoid vaccination before traveling to the next country I'll visit, Morocco. Where can I get a typhoid vaccination in Zagreb?

Comment: If we had a "featured questions" newsletter or something I would add this. So much better than the usual "my visa was rejected now what" etc questions.

Comment: @chx Some exchanges have a Twitter account they use to report on the more interesting questions. One of my first questions I asked on the exchange was spread in this way.

Comment: @chx that's actually how I found this question, in the weekly newsletter

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I ended up getting a typhoid shot at the Zagreb city-run **Andrija Stampar Teaching Institute of Public Health** (Croatian: Zavod za javno zdravstvo "Dr. Andrija Štampar", [link to official website](http://www.stampar.hr/en/)). The address is [Mirogojska 16, 10000 Zagreb, Croatia](https://goo.gl/maps/fuYpbShLxCv). Look for the signs for "epidemiologija", just to the left inside the main entrance.

The medical staff spoke good English, the cost was around $30 (April 2016), and I was in and out in about 20 minutes.