# Where can I get a cholera vaccination in Ljubljana?

Tags: health, slovenia, ljubljana

I'm living in Ljubljana and I'm going in few weeks to Dominican Republic (in a region near the border with Haiti) and I need to get a cholera vaccination. In case that is not possible no get this vaccine in Ljubljana, where could I go?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the asker's access to medical services in their home town.

Comment: Ask your doctor!

Comment: This type of questions is very well on-topic here, see e.g. http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/66241/32134 and http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/69154/32134. Voting to leave open.

Comment: The national health institute does all kinds of vaccinations, but not for cholera: http://www.nijz.si/sites/www.nijz.si/files/uploaded/cenik_storitev_ambulante_za_cepljenje_velja_od_1_1_2016.pdf

Comment: @JonathanReez, there is a reason for that. Cholera vaccination in not really effective and is discouraged by [NIJZ (in Slovenian)](http://www.nijz.si/sl/kolera).

Comment: @mts FWIW the two questions you linked were explicitly "how can I get vaccinated for X while *traveling in* Y," not "I live in Y, where can I get vaccinated for X?", which might be travel-related on its own merits but isn't exactly the same.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is **nowhere**. The [National Institute of Health](http://www.nijz.si/) (Slovenia's main organization for [vaccinations](http://www.nijz.si/sites/www.nijz.si/files/uploaded/cenik_storitev_ambulante_za_cepljenje_velja_od_1_1_2016.pdf)) [doesn't consider the existing cholera vaccinations to be effective enough](http://www.nijz.si/sl/kolera). Rough translation:

> Vaccination against cholera is poorly effective, and therefore is not recommended.

I've received the same reply when contacting them by email:

> Sorry, 
>   vaccination against cholera is not possible in any of the Travel Clinic of National Institute of Public Heath in Slovenia, because the vaccine against cholera is not available.
>
> Best regards,
>   Ondina Jordan Markočič, MD, spec.
>
> National Institute of Public Health, Regional Unit Ljubljana

The World Health Organization [has a similar recommendation](http://www.who.int/cholera/prevention_control/recommendations/en/index1.html):

> Measures for the prevention of cholera mostly consist of providing clean water and proper sanitation to populations who do not yet have access to basic services. Health education and good food hygiene are equally important. Communities should be reminded of basic hygienic behaviours, including the necessity of systematic hand-washing with soap after defecation and before handling food or eating, as well as safe preparation and conservation of food.

Avoid potentially contaminated sources of water, always wash your hands before eating, observe basic hygiene standards, and you should be protected from cholera without any vaccinations.